# azure site URL adding extra text

Tags: url, azure

I've a web application which is hosted on Azure. The problem , I am facing is, sometimes the URL of my site becomes like below:

http://mysite.cloudapp.net/(F(rjGIaz1Pqyx99JkNL3YW22kgRhSJR4iCAcSjv0jCgstINZv09GMwEDawb39bow5SsvclXtFJEV9A1P3qPIrh26nkvNLg0qdWIWV3S8eRT1AXvQ69dyCcsYmzEeogIHJTjLgfq0i71cgzwdIAhXXQNdQz5Hk1))
/webform.aspx

instead of http://mysite.cloudapp.net/webform.aspx

I don't have any idea, where this extra text is coming from.

When the extra text added to my url, from that time onwards mysite stop functioning and I could only login into it, can not do anything ?

Did anyone have come across such issues on Azure ? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Its your user session id. Set cookieless attribute on sessionState in web.config to false, like this:

```
<sessionState cookieless="False" />
```

See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx